# Play LPCM Non-interleaved Audio over PC

Tags: c#, iphone, audio-streaming, audioformat

I create audio buffer is LPCM 8000Hz 8Bit 2 channel format. I send this buffer to PC over network. 
I try to play this byte buffer on PC. I add wav header to this byte array and play but I cant get reasonable voice.

How Can I get reasonable voice?

My PC programming Lang. C#...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "reasonable voice", but 8khz 8 bit audio is always going to sound like you are listening to a wax cylinder recording, it's simply too low def to sound any good.

Comment: I can get audio on another Iphone. And sound is good. Sound Quality is not important for me. I want to say something on Iphone and hear on PC.